# Is there a better way to extend a Bezier Curve?

Tags: interface, workflow, bezier-curves

It seems very tedious and therefore slow to extend Bezier curves while creating them in Blender. The docs say to select two control points and <kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide*. This makes extending the curve unreasonably difficult, since after adding an additional control point (which is where you need the new point to be) you must then manually move both the end point and the new point into their desired positions, adjusting their handles, etc.

When extending the curve, even moving the current end point to where you want the next point to be (prior to subdividing) is odd and difficult, requiring many adjustments after subdividing to get the new point. Is there a better way?

Comment: The editing tools for curves are indeed not as advanced as in other apps out there. If you are editing complex curves it might be a good idea do it in Illustrator, Inkscape, or any of the other sophisticated vector graphics programs. Then export your curves as SVG files and import them into blender.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a bezeir curve.

In edit mode select a control point at the start or end of the curve.

You can press:

- <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude (and move) a new connected point
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Left Mouse Click</kbd> to create a new connected point.
- To make new control points that are unconnected to the existing curve deselect any previously selected control points and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Left Mouse Click</kbd>
- <kbd>V</kbd> to set handle type (vector straight, aligned, free, etc...) 
  New points are the same type of active (last selected) control point.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to close a curve

For more info see the [Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/curves/editing/introduction.html?highlight=curves)